# onKeyPress input field focus in Wix

Tags: javascript, velo

I've put together a working code setup for a wix dynamic page that runs through a repeater and filters for the text included in an input field. This is great barring for 1 quirk - after the timeout, the text input submits and you aren't able to carry on typing. I want the focus to remain on the input even after the timeout.

The relevant code is below - I've tried to retain the focus on the relevant input:

```
export function addressSearchBox_keyPress(event, $w) {
if (debounceTimer) {
clearTimeout(debounceTimer);
debounceTimer = undefined;
}
debounceTimer = setTimeout(() => {
filter($w('#addressSearchBox').value, lastFilterCity);
 //logging output to console
 console.log($w('#addressSearchBox').value);

//attempting to refocus to the addressSearchBox
$w("#addressSearchBox").focus();
}, 800);

}
```

Any idea on why this wouldn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [this example](https://www.wix.com/velo/example/search-a-database). I think it does exactly what you want.